# Generate only one specific endpoint from API

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

My current setup for OpenAPI Generator in `build.gradle`.

```
def openApiGeneratorConfig = {
    classpath configurations.openApiGenerator
    systemProperties = ["apis": "", "models": ""]
    mainClass = 'org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator'
    args 'generate'
    args '-o', "$rootDir/external"
    args '-t', "$rootDir/external/src/main/resources/codegen/templates/"
    args '--skip-validate-spec'
    args "--import-mappings", "Instant=java.time.Instant,YearMonth=java.time.YearMonth,LocalDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime"
    args "--type-mappings", "double=BigDecimal"
}

def configFilesRoute = "$rootDir/external/src/main/resources/config/swagger"

task generateExternalApiClient(type: JavaExec) {
    configure openApiGeneratorConfig
    systemProperties = ["apis": "ContractSearch#findContractByCustomerId"]
    args "-i", "http://localhost:9901/v2/api-docs"
    args "-c", "$configFilesRoute/loan.json"
}
```

In `ContractSearch` (Api) I have a lot of endpoints (operations) and I need to generate only one specific endpoint.
So before this (migrate to OpenAPI Generator), I used Swagger CodeGen and if I specified the operation after api with using symbol # as separator, then it worked fine, and it generated only one specific endpoint.
But now after migrating to OpenAPI Generator, it is not work in this behaviour. I googled and also checked documentation, didn't find any answer to my question.

Java 17. Spring Boot 2.7, Gradle 8.2, OpenAPI Generator CLI 6.6.0

I tried adding difference arguments in OpenAPI config, but also didn't help me.

Comment: @ojacomarket Yes I tried. But ChatGPT didn't provide any good solutions. I think in this case ChatGPT can't give any solution.